# Convert PHP SHA1 to Ruby

Tags: php, ruby, sha1

I have this algorithm in PHP:

```
$encoded_key = 'WHllcnRGYTY3eWpUNjQ'; 
$decoded_key = base64_decode($encoded_key); 
// XyertFa67yjT64 
$params_string = implode('', $params); 
//U215250.00121715620http://partner.domain.ru/order/U215/successhttp://partner.domain.ru/order/U215/fail 
$raw_signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $params_string, $decoded_key, true); 
// Byte-encoded, hex: c6881d8665afbb46a93a16b34bd152878a19ab3a 

$encoded_signature = base64_encode($raw_signature); 
// xogdhmWvu0apOhazS9FSh4oZqzo=
```

I'm trying to port this code to Ruby and get the same result but Base64 and OpenSSL can't help me. Does any one know whats wrong?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Doing all like in php instruction, start with 
`decode64`
`Base64.decode64("WHllcnRGYTY3eWpUNjQ")`
 gives me
**XyertFa67yjT** - first strange thing.. not **XyertFa67yjT64** as in php

Comment: But even if i take **XyertFa67yjT64** as key and $params_string, and use it with 
`OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('SHA1', key, string)` result will be **c3353924557f97d80fd53f9063f186b1e4d8df3c**

Comment: @rossman, Thank you for the added information.  It really belongs in the question, though--would you please click "edit" and add the additional information to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you are using `HMAC.hexdigest` instead of `HMAC.digest`. Your PHP code is generating a raw HMAC and then encoding it in base 64. Therefore, you need to do the same thing in Ruby.

The other problem is the base 64 decoding step of the key. The key you entered is not padded correctly and will therefore be truncated by Ruby's base 64 library. For example:

```
encoded_key = "WHllcnRGYTY3eWpUNjQ"

Base64.decode64(encoded_key)
#=> "XyertFa67yjT"
# incomplete!

Base64.decode64("#{encoded_key}=\n")
#=> "XyertFa67yjT64"
# this is what you actually want
```

The padding and the final newline are there to ensure that the base 64 encoded data is complete, since it marks the end. However, it is possible to manually add the padding and just assume that the data is complete:

```
require 'base64'
require 'openssl'

def base64_pad(unpadded_str)
  padding = case unpadded_str.size % 3
    when 1 then "=="
    when 2 then "="
  end
  "#{unpadded_str}#{padding}\n"
end

encoded_key = "WHllcnRGYTY3eWpUNjQ"
key = Base64.decode64(base64_pad(encoded_key))
#=> "XyertFa67yjT64"

string = "U215250.00121715620http://partner.domain.ru/order/U215/successhttp://partner.domain.ru/order/U215/fail"

Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('SHA1', key, string))
#=> "xogdhmWvu0apOhazS9FSh4oZqzo=\n"
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you! in fact I already found an answer and create valid code, but now all even more clearly for me. I think that example of key was symply incorect. I miss moment with hexdigest/digest.. sad.